# how to silence robocopy when mirroring directory

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I would like to mirror a directory with robocopy without any output except for the status header and the summary at the end. The command I am using at the moment is `robocopy /MIR /NFL /NDL /NC /NS /NP dir1 dir2`. If I create a file in `dir2` that is not present in `dir1` and run this command it gets deleted (as expected) but also generates output (not expected and not wanted). Is there a way to make robocopy behave like I want?

Edit: I still want to see the Job Header and Job Summary though.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only way seems to be to pipe the output, e.g. `robocopy /MIR /NFL /NDL dir1 dir2 | Select-String -Pattern "*EXTRA" -NotMatch -SimpleMatch` in PowerShell, or `robocopy /MIR /NFL /NDL dir1 dir2 | findstr /lv "*EXTRA"` in CMD.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can redirect the output (Stream 1 for Standard Output, Stream 2 for Error output) either to `NUL` (just disregard it) or to a file (for later viewing):

```
robocopy /MIR /NFL /NDL /NC /NS /NP dir1 dir2 >nul 2>&1
```

or

```
robocopy /MIR /NFL /NDL /NC /NS /NP dir1 dir2 >robolog.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: But I would like to still be able to get the Job Header and Job summary though.. Sorry I was probably not that clear in my question.

Comment: I haven't found a way to silence the deleted files either. Had to settle for >nul which in my case is okay.