# How to use robocopy mirror without output?

Tags: powershell, logging, robocopy, mirror, mirroring

I am trying to delete a folder using robocopy mirroring like this:
`Start-Process -FilePath "robocopy.exe" -ArgumentList "$emptyDir $sourcePath /mir /e /np /ns /nc /njs /njh /nfl /ndl" -Wait -PassThru -NoNewWindow` but still get a line of output for every deleted file [image]

I tried adding `>nul 2>&1` as explained in another [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47157426/how-to-silence-robocopy-when-mirroring-directory) `Start-Process -FilePath "robocopy.exe" -ArgumentList "$emptyDir $sourcePath /mir /e /np /ns /nc /njs /njh /nfl /ndl >nul 2>&1" -Wait -PassThru -NoNewWindow` but still get the same output.

Comment: have you tried piping the entire `Start-Process` line to `Out-Null`?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician, `Out-Null` can never silence the output _from the program_ launched by `Start-Process`, it can only silence `Start-Process` _own_ output (and simply omitting `-PassThru` would make it output nothing). Output from a `Start-Process -NoNewWindow` launched console application can fundamentally not be suppressed in PowerShell, as it writes directly to the console, outside PowerShell's control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're running `robocopy` in the *current* console window (`-NoNewWindow`), *synchronously* (`-Wait`), there is ***no* reason to use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)** at all - **just invoke `robocopy` *directly***, which also allows you to use `>` redirections effectively:

```bash
robocopy.exe $emptyDir $sourcePath /mir /e /np /ns /nc /njs /njh /nfl /ndl *>$null
```

Note:

- Direct execution makes a program's stdout and stderr output directly available to PowerShell, via its success and error [output streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams).
- `*>$null` is a convenient PowerShell shortcut for silencing *all* output streams - see [about_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection).
- Another benefit of direct invocation is that the external program's process *exit code* is reported in PowerShell's [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode).

See also:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334633/45375) provides background information.
- [GitHub docs issue #6239](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6239) provides guidance on when use of  `Start-Process` is and isn't appropriate.

---

As for **what you tried**:

- You fundamentally cannot suppress output from a process launched with `Start-Process -NoNewWindow` on the *PowerShell* side.
- Trying to silence command output *at the source*, i.e. as part of the target process' *command line* with `>nul 2>&1`, would only work if *`cmd.exe`* were the `-FilePath` argument and you passed a `robocopy` command to *it*. `>` redirections are a *shell* feature, and `robocopy` itself isn't a shell.

Comment: You might want to try to use splatting instead, as this can be a better way to sidestep quoting issues.  robocopy won't present too many of them, but other apps will.

Comment: splatting sidesteps the normal attempt to interpet spacing and quotes within arguments and instead passes each element in the array as an argument.  So, yeah, it does help with quoting.  _a lot_.  Calling apps like FFmpeg, net, or sc would be a lot harder if splatting was not a thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to pass arguments via splatting, and then use the object pipeline to parse line by line.

In the example below, I'm going to split the arguments into two groups, in case you wanted to change out the options programmatically.

```
$roboFileArgs = @(
    <#
    If you're sure your argument is already a string or
    a primitive type, there's no need to quote it.
    #>
    $emptyDir
    $sourcePath
)

$roboFlags = "/mir","/e","/np","/ns","/nc","/njs","/njh","/nfl","/ndl"

# We can use splatting to pass both lists of arguments
robocopy.exe @roboFileArgs @roboFlags |
    Foreach-Object { 
    <#
      process output line by line and turn it into objects
      or pipe to Out-Null if you truly don't care.
    #>
    }
```